# Confusion over datetime64, timestamp and pd.DateOffset()

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have this data, dtype datetime64[ns]

```
df.date_month
Output: 
0         2018-09-01
1         2018-09-01
2         2018-09-01
3         2018-09-01
4         2018-09-01
             ...    
Name: date_month, Length: 4839993, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

If I run a for loop and add pd.Offset, the code runs.

```
for i in df.date_month[0:10]:
  print(i + pd.DateOffset(months=12))

Output:
2019-09-01 00:00:00
2019-09-01 00:00:00
2019-09-01 00:00:00
2019-09-01 00:00:00
```

however, if I use unique(), the code breaks.

```
for i in df.date_month.unique():
  print(i + pd.DateOffset(months=12))

Output:
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3708796390803054> in <module>
      1 for i in df.date_month.unique():
----> 2   print(i + pd.DateOffset(months=12))

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

Can someone help me why this happens? Does unique() transform the data in some way?

```
df.date_month.unique()
Output: 
array(['2018-09-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-04-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-12-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-11-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-07-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-05-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-06-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-10-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2018-08-01T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: I guess an implicitly type conversion happens. You can swap the positions using `pd.DateOffset(months=12) + i`.

Comment: @ILS that works - but a bit strange to me why.

Comment: I didn't dig deep. When `i` of type `numpy.datetime64` comes first, it converts `pd.DateOffset(months=12)` to a numpy object and then performs the add operation, but `numpy` doesn't know `pandas.DateOffset` and treats it as an general object. Therefore `+` fails. Conversely, `pandas` knows `numpy.datetime64`, so `+` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, `unique()` returns an array from the `Series` you are passing it. See --> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html

You more than likely want to use `drop_duplicates()` --> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

i.e.

```py
for i in df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date_month']).date_month:
    print(i + pd.DateOffset(months=12))
```